# Gnuradio OOT not seeing sources?

Tags: gnuradio

When trying to write an OOT block for Gnuradio, I ran `cmake ../`, and then `make`. The make process successfully builds some objects, but when it gets to the step:

```
Linking CXX executable test-XXXXXXXX
```

there is the problem:

```
libgnuradio-XXXXXXXX.so: undefined reference to 'YYYYYYYY'
```

`YYYYYYYY` is a function defined in a `.cc` file, which I add to the `_impl.cc` for the block using a header. This source is apparently not being found, despite being in the same source directory as the `_impl.cc` file.

Cmake explicitly warns not to make any modifications to the generated Makefile, and it is a fairly complex makefile anyway, so I would be hesitant to try messing with it. Is there another way to direct make to include that additional source when linking?

Comment: You will need to add your source code. Without, this is just guessing, which I'd be less opposed to on a mailing list, where the dialectic nature of discussion is easier to embrace, but on SO well-asked questions should definitely include the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to look at the CMakeLists.txt at the top of your OOT folder. It is most likely that you are seeing a link problem and that a package dependency is not satisfied. The cmake find_package utility can be used to determine if a dependency is available on the system. If you look at the cmake/Modules directory under the main OOT folder, there should be a couple of examples. Cmake ships with many modules so it's likely what you need will exist.

By adding some find_package logic to the main CMakeLists.txt file, and then blowing away the build directory and making it again and executing "cmake ../", the dependency issue should be apparent. Put another way, whatever libgnuradio-*.so thinks is missing must belong to a package that is not installed on your system. Using find_package will confirm it, and then the answer is to install it.

Look at some other CMakeLists.txt files, say, in gr-digital, for find_package examples.